# The retry strategy using requests is unsuccessful

Tags: python, python-requests

I set a timeout to retry, but in fact I only requested one time and an error was thrown.
What I expect is to retry 2 times after the timeout, and if it still times out, catch the exception and throw an error.

```
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import Retry
from my_exception import MyException
import requests


s = Session()
adapter = HTTPAdapter(
    max_retries=Retry(
        connect=2,
        read=2,
        status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504],
    )
)
s.mount("http://", adapter)
s.mount("https://", adapter)


def get(url):
    try:
        r = s.get(url, timeout=(1, 60))
        r.raise_for_status()
        return r
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        if "timed out" in str(e) or "Time-out" in str(e):
            raise MyException(500, "Requests timeout.")
        raise MyException(r.status_code, str(e))


def post(url, data):
    try:
        r = s.post(url, data=data, timeout=(1, 60))
        r.raise_for_status()
        return r
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        if "timed out" in str(e) or "Time-out" in str(e):
            raise MyException(500, "Requests timeout.")
        raise MyException(r.status_code, str(e))
```

Comment: Who is raising the timeout ? Is it the server or client ?

Comment: Normally it is the server.